# Regular expression in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, solaris

I try to use regex in a sed command. I try to replace a pattern. My pattern is a line in /etc/security/policy.conf file. The value is unknown it should be either:

#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO or LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=4 (or any number here). I want to replace found pattern with the value LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6. So I tried the command:

```
sed 's/#*LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/g' ./policy.conf
```

But it didn't look to be working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
sed -i 's/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=.*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/g' filename
```

I test like this and it works:

```
echo "LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=4\n#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO" | sed 's/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=.*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/g'
```

[EDIT]

After checking other's answer, I am not sure whether you want to replace `#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO` to `LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6` or `#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6`.

My above answer will change `#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO` to `#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6`

If you want to change change `#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO` to `LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6`, try:
`sed -i 's/^#*LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=.*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/g' filename`

In summary:

```
echo "LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=4\n#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO" | sed 's/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=.*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/g'
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
echo "LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=4\n#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO" | sed 's/^#*LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=.*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/g'
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
```

Comment: cool. actually I edit my answer in case you have different requirements.

Answer (score 2):

give this a try:

```
sed 's/^#\?\s*LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=[^=]*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/'
```

test with some example:

```
# LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO
#LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=NO
 LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=4
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=4

kent$  sed 's/^#\?\s*LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=[^=]*/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6/' f
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES=6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed '/LOCK_AFTER_RETRIES/s/=.*/=6/g'  ./policy.conf
```